# Word for taking some action hoping it will encourage you to improve your behavior

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word that means taking some action hoping it will encourage their own good behavior. I'm certain this word exists but I can't remember if it's an adverb or adjective.

As an example:

Alice wants to improve her personal finances. She buys a subscription to You Need a Budget hoping it will encourage her to start using it and get a handle on her spending. The adverb would be, "Alice ___*ly* purchased You Need a Budget," or the adjective would be, "Alice made a ____ purchase of You Need a Budget"

Another example would be someone with a poor diet suddenly purchasing a lot of vegetables hoping that it will spur them into eating healthier. This person either, "___*ly* purchased vegetables," or "made a ____ purchase."

Words that are similar but not quite right:

- **Optimistically**: The person isn't really being optimistic, they're trying to force themselves to be better.
- **Proactively**: The person isn't anticipating something, they're trying to cause their own behavior to change.

Comment: I don't think it's really the right thing, but the practice of doing something to influence your future decision-making is often referred to as "self-hacking."

Comment: _proactively_ is what occured to me instantly, and I think that fits the bill nicely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The word I was looking for was *aspirational*.